# PHP loop sum from database

Tags: php

```
$st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE group_id=?");
$st->execute(array($id));

    if($st->rowCount() >= 1){
        foreach ($st as $row) {
            $counter = $row["paymentAmount"];
            $start = 1;

            for($start; $start < $st->rowCount(); $start++) {
                $counter = $counter + $row["paymentAmount"];
                }
        }
```

It actually print out `$row["paymentAmount"] + $row["paymentAmount"]` and so on, depending on how many `$row["paymentAmount"]` there is. But the problem is that the last output from `$row["paymentAmount"]` is 2500.

There is:
10000
10000
2500

And the result is: 7500
I want it to be: 22500

And if the last result is 3000 it shall be 23000. So what I simply need is this code to take every row from the database, just not the latest one.

Edit: I want it outside of the SQL query

Comment: why not do the sum with your database query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let your database handle the sum unless you have a legitimate reason why it needs to be handled in PHP.  The database is more efficient with this type of operation and you avoid a loop in PHP.

```
SELECT SUM(paymentAmount) AS TotalPaymentAmount FROM invoices WHERE group_id = ?
```

You can then change your PHP to return just one row:

```
$row = $st->fetch();
echo $row["TotalPaymentAmount"];
```

---

If you need to do this calculation outside of SQL, just change your loop:

```
if($st->rowCount() >= 1){
        //init the counter to 0 before you loop through your rows
        $counter = 0;
        //the foreach will iterate over your result set and add the paymentAmount to $counter.
        foreach ($st as $row) {
            $counter += $row["paymentAmount"];
        }
        //echo results outside of the loop
        echo $counter;
}
```

Comment: This just echo out the first row from the database, even though I had it in my loop. How can I fix this?

Comment: @mrfloden - I've updated my answer.  If you don't want to allow the database to handle the calculation, just modify your PHP loop so that $counter is initialized outside the loop and aggregated inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PHP logic for something like this. The functionality is built right into SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(paymentAmount) FROM invoices WHERE group_id=?
```

Comment: @mrfloden just echo the result of that query.

Comment: You can use `SELECT SUM(paymentAmount) AS total ...`, or use `$sth->fetchColumn();` after your query.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I tried $st->fetchColumn(); under my $counter = $counter + $row2["paymentAmount"];, but it just fetches the first. How may I change this?

Comment: Also it doesn't SUM it, it return null

Answer (score 0):

If you need to code this outside SQL on purpose (e.g. because you need to do further processing for each row), then I'd code this as follows:

```
if ($st->rowCount() >= 1) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($st as $row) {
        $counter += $row["paymentAmount"];
    }
}
```